# Where are all of the truck dealers?

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

When you first start Euro Truck Simulator 2 you are given your choice of your "favourite" truck design. Your choice here decides on which dealer is made visible to you on your map at the start of the game.

Because of this I know that Scania have a shop in Hannover, what I was wondering is where are all of the other truck dealers?

In which cities can I find their shops?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This list should contain all dealers from both the base game as well as the Going East DLC:

**Big dealers:**

- DAF: Glasgow, Amsterdam
- IVECO: Frankfurt am Main, Wien
- MAN: München, Berlin
- MAJESTIC: Stuttgart, Genève, Warszava
- RENAULT: Paris, Praha, Budapest
- SCANIA: Milano, Manchester, Hannover
- VOLVO: London, Luxembourg

**Small dealers:**

- DAF: Cardiff, Bremen, Leipzig, Salzburg, Zürich
- IVECO: Torino, Grimsby, Hamburg, Brussel
- MAN: Edinburgh, Birmingham, Dortmund, Calais, Bern, Kraków
- MAJESTIC: Bratislava, Szczecin, Rotterdam, Plymouth, Newcastle-upon-Tyne
- RENAULT: Lyon, Düsseldorf, Felixstowe, Rostock
- SCANIA: Aberdeen, Lille, Gdańsk, Strasbourg, Dresden
- VOLVO: Verona, Nürnberg, Wrocław, Osnabrück

Comment: Note: maybe this answer can be improved from http://trucksim.wikia.com/wiki/Truck_Dealers , and maybe that wiki can be improved from this answer.

Answer (score 7):

The [accepted answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/106439) is significantly out of date - a number of new truck dealers have been added, both in updates to the base game as well as new DLCs, and the game no longer distinguishes between big and small dealers. However, since my attempts at improving the existing answer have been rejected, I'm posting the up-to-date information as a separate answer. Not ideal, but there you go.

The list below contains all of the truck dealers from both the base game as well as the *Going East*, *Scandinavia*, *Vive la France*, *Italia*, *Beyond the Baltic Sea*, *Road to the Black Sea* and *Iberia* DLCs:

- **DAF**: Amsterdam, Bergen, Bordeaux, Bremen, Burgos, Cardiff, Catania, Glasgow, Iași, Leipzig, Санкт-Петербу́рг (Saint Petersburg), Salzburg, Sevilla, Tartu, Zürich
- **IVECO**: Almería, Brussel, București (Bucharest), Constanța, Frankfurt am Main, Galați, Gijón, Grimsby, Hamburg, Helsinki, Klaipėda, København (Copenhagen), Le Mans, Roma, Torino (Turin), Wien (Vienna), Zaragoza
- **MAN**: Ajaccio, Berlin, Bern, Birmingham, Calais, Cluj-Napoca, Córdoba, Dortmund, Edinburgh, Kraków, Linköping, Madrid, Marseilles, München (Munich), Porto, Rīga, Taranto
- **Mercedes-Benz**: Badajos, Bologna, Bratislava, Genève, İstanbul, Калининград (Kaliningrad), Kalmar, Nantes, Newcastle-upon-Tyne, Plymouth, Rotterdam, Sassari, Stuttgart, Szczecin, Valladolid, Warszawa
- **RENAULT**: Barcelona, Bourges, Budapest, Düsseldorf, Felixstowe, Kaunas, León, Lyon, Oslo, Palermo, Paris, Praha (Prague), Rostock, Szeged, Со́фия (Sofia), Toulouse
- **SCANIA**: Aberdeen, Bayonne, Brest, Cagliari, Dresden, Firenze, Gdańsk, Hannover, Lahti, Lille, Lisboa, Manchester, Milano, Pitești, Stockholm, Strasbourg, Tallinn
- **VOLVO**: Albacete, Brașov, Göteborg, Graz, Limoges, London, Luxembourg, Málaga, Napoli, Nürnberg, Osnabrück, Пловдив (Plovdiv), Turku, Verona, Vilnius, Wrocław

Answer (score -1):

**DAF**: Glasgow, Amsterdam ,Cardiff, Bremen, Leipzig, Salzburg, Zürich

**IVECO**: Frankfurt am Main, Wien, Torino, Grimsby, Hamburg, Brussel

**MAN**: München, Berlin, Edinburgh, Birmingham, Dortmund, Calais, Bern, Kraków

**MAJESTIC**: Stuttgart, Genève, Warszawa, Bratislava, Szczecin, Rotterdam, Plymouth, Newcastle-upon-Tyne

**RENAULT**: Paris, Praha, Budapest, Lyon, Düsseldorf, Felixstowe, Rostock

**SCANIA**: Milano, Manchester, Hannover, Aberdeen, Lille, Gdańsk, Strasbourg, Dresden

**VOLVO**: London, Luxembourg, Verona, Nürnberg, Wrocław, Osnabrück

Comment: Mercedes-Benz: Badajos, Bologna, Bratislava, Genève, İstanbul, Калининград (Kaliningrad), Kalmar, Nantes, Newcastle-upon-Tyne, Plymouth, Rotterdam, Sassari, Stuttgart, Szczecin, Valladolid, Warszawa

Comment: You can edit your own answer, there's no need to add information as a comment.

Comment: This seems to be merely copied from the existing answers (mainly the accepted answer, but the comment is from my answer).